# fancytree not loading json data

Tags: php, jquery, json, loading, fancytree

I am attempting to use fancytree to display some data returned from a php rest service. The data returned by the service has been validated via JSONLint and it appears in the format shown in the fancytree docs.

If I have the developer tools window (Chrome) open it shows the error "Uncaught Error: Not implemented" in file jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2.

When I validated the JSON data returned I was using the Advanced Rest Client (Google App) and I removed the double quotes which surrounded the string displayed by Advanced Rest Client, and then pasted the value into JSONLint.

My jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
         var phpAPI = "http://localhost/clubjudge/api/JSONClassTree2";
         $.getJSON(phpAPI)
          .done(function(json) {
              alert(json);
              $("#tree").fancytree({
                 source: json
                 }
              );
           })
          .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
              var err = textStatus + ", "+ error;
              console.log("Request Failed: "+ err );
   });

});
</script>
```

Any help greatly appreciated as I have been messing with this for a couple of days now.
PS. I hope the included code has formatted properly. The 'preview' doesn't seem to look right.

Figured I'd better post the JSON data.

```
[
 {"title":"A - Australian Native","key":"1","children":[
     {"title":"A1 - Australian Native Dendrobium Species","key":"7"},
     {"title":"A2 - Australian Native Any Other Species","key":"8"},
     {"title":"A3 - Australian Native Dendrobium Hybrid","key":"9"},
     {"title":"A4 - Australian Native Any Other Hybrid","key":"10"},
     {"title":"A5 - Australian Native Seedling","key":"11"}
 ]},
 {"title":"B - Cymbidium","key":"2","children":[
     {"title":"B1 - Standard Type Cymbidium","key":"3"},
     {"title":"B2 - Intermediate Type Cymbidium","key":"4"},
     {"title":"B3 - Miniature Type Cymbidium","key":"5"},
     {"title":"B4 - Cymbidium Species","key":"6"}
 ]}
]
```

Sorry I realise there is a lot. Once again this is what the Advanced Rest Client shows (after trimming off the outer double quotes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load JSON data putting in request to source:

```
$("#tree").fancytree({
  source: $.ajax({
    url: "/clubjudge/api/JSONClassTree2",
    dataType: "json"
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably your json variable is JSON string and FancyTree expects it to be JS Object, so you should use JSON.parse() first. It helped in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solves your problem, but you  don't need to issue a separate ajax request. Fancytree supports this directly:

```
$("#tree").fancytree({
  source: {
    url: "/clubjudge/api/JSONClassTree2",
    cache: false
  },
  ...
});
```

See here for details: https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki/TutorialLoadData